# Valor nulo al intentar obtener dato desde otro objeto

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en un portal inmobiliario y tengo en una tabla `inmueble` el tipo de propiedad (entiéndase "vivienda", "local", entre otros) al cargar un inmueble devuelve los datos que se encuentran en la base de datos menos el tipo de propiedad el cual se encuentra en otra tabla llamada `tipoInmueble`, éste valor lo devuelve como nulo, para explicarme mejor voy a colocar parte del código:

En la capa del **dominio** tengo lo siguiente:

```
public TipoInmueble tipo { get; set; }
 public int id { get; set; }
 public string titulo { get; set; }
```

Éstos son solo algunos campos ya que creo que no vale la pena ponerlos todos.

En la capa de **persistencia** tengo lo siguiente:

```
 private Inmueble cargarInmuebles(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        var objI = new Inmueble();
        var objTipo = new TipoInmueble();
        var objSubTipo = new SubTipoInmueble();
        objI.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
        objI.titulo = Convert.ToString(reader["titulo"]);
        objI.contenido = Convert.ToString(reader["contenido"]);
        objI.precio = Convert.ToInt32(reader["precio"]);
        objI.rooms = Convert.ToInt32(reader["rooms"]);
        objI.bathrooms = Convert.ToInt32(reader["bathrooms"]);
        objI.garage = Convert.ToInt32(reader["garage"]);
        var tipoInmueble = new tipoInmuebleMapper().obtenerPorId(objTipo.id); <-- Ésta es la línea en la cual me devuelve el valor nulo en vez de devolver el valor del id correspondiente al tipo de propiedad.
        var subTipoInmueble = new subTipoInmuebleMapper().obtenerPorId(objSubTipo.id);            
        objI.ciudad = Convert.ToString(reader["ciudad"]);
        objI.barrio = Convert.ToString(reader["barrio"]);
        return objI;
    }
```

El código del `obtenerPorId()` de la clase `tipoInmuebleMapper`

```
  public TipoInmueble obtenerPorId(int xId)
        {
            var param = new List<SqlParameter>();
            var id = new SqlParameter();
            id.ParameterName = "@id";
            id.Value = xId;
            param.Add(id);
            var con = AbrirConexion();
            var reader = select("SELECT * FROM tipoInmueble WHERE id = @id", CommandType.Text, param, con, null);
            TipoInmueble t = null;
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                t = cargarTipoInmueble(reader);
            }
            CerrarConexion(con);
            return t;
        }
```

Éste es el método que carga al reader.

```
        public List<Inmueble> obtenerTodos()
    {
        List<Inmueble> listaInmuebles = new List<Inmueble>();
        var param = new List<SqlParameter>();
        var con = AbrirConexion();
        var reader = select("SELECT * FROM inmueble", CommandType.Text, param, con, null);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            listaInmuebles.Add(cargarInmuebles(reader));
        }
        CerrarConexion(con);
        return listaInmuebles;            
    }
```

Quisiera saber el por qué del valor `nulo` o como es que puedo lograr que se obtenga el valor del id correspondiente.

Gracias de antemano y siéntanse libres de solicitar cualquier información adicional.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de `tipoInmuebleMapper` y en especifico el método `obtenerPorId` ? Puede que el error esté ahí.

Comment: Hola, te has planteado en la consulta de tu `reader` incluir los `JOIN` necesarios para enlazar las tablas de `tipoInmueble`? Entiendo que debe de haber un `idTipoInmueble` relacionado como clave foránea.

Comment: Además, viendo tu código se puede observar que  `objTipo.id` es siempre `null` ya que no estableces ningún valor en esa propiedad.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Hola, éste es el código del obtenerPorId, dicho sea de paso, no le encuentrro sentido ya que se le tiene que pasar un id como parámetro pero por lo que veo en el reader nunca le va a pasar ese parámetro, no sé si me explico, ahora coloco el código. Saludos y gracias por contestar.

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra Hola Sergio, no, simplemente hice un Select pero como comenté anteriormente me parece como que no tiene sentido lo que estoy haciendo ya que estoy buscando un tipo de inmueble por su id pero a su vez en el reader nunca le paso ese id, en realidad mi idea era sacar ese id de la base de datos e intentar pasárselo al obtenerPorId() no sé si logro explicarme, saludos!

Comment: Hola. Puedes poner el código de cómo cargas el `reader` que le pasas al método `cargarInmuebles`?

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra Ahí puse el método, supongo que te referís a ese, por cierto, en la base de datos los inmuebles tienen un campo el cual guarda el tipo de propiedad, si cambio un poco el código logro hacer que devuelva el valor de ese campo cuando voy viendo paso por paso pero cuando llega al final muestra como que es nulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viendo las consultas que haces en tus métodos te recomiendo hagas los siguiente:
Realizar un `JOIN` con la tabla de `tiposInmueble`

```
public List<Inmueble> obtenerTodos()
{
    List<Inmueble> listaInmuebles = new List<Inmueble>();
    var param = new List<SqlParameter>();
    var con = AbrirConexion();
    // establecer un JOIN con la tabla de Tipos de Inmueble.
    // te recomiendo tambien poner las columnas necearias para tu método, es mala práctica el devolver todo
    // en tipoInmueble.descripcion me lo he inventado
    var query = "SELECT inmueble.id, inmueble.titulo, inmueble.contenido, inmueble.precio, inmueble.rooms, inmueble.bathrooms,inmueble.garage, inmueble.ciudad, inmueble.barrio, inmueble.idTipoInmueble, tipoInmueble.descripcionTipoInmueble FROM inmueble INNER JOIN tipoInmueble ON inmueble.idTipoInmueble = tipoInmueble.Id"
    var reader = select(query, CommandType.Text, param, con, null);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        listaInmuebles.Add(cargarInmuebles(reader));
    }
    CerrarConexion(con);
    return listaInmuebles;            
}
```

luego recuperar. Estableciendo el la propiedad `tipo` como un `TipoInmueble` (necesitaríamos saber la estructura de esta clase)

```
private Inmueble cargarInmuebles(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var objI = new Inmueble();
    var objTipo = new TipoInmueble();
    var objSubTipo = new SubTipoInmueble();
    objI.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
    objI.titulo = Convert.ToString(reader["titulo"]);
    objI.contenido = Convert.ToString(reader["contenido"]);
    objI.precio = Convert.ToInt32(reader["precio"]);
    objI.rooms = Convert.ToInt32(reader["rooms"]);
    objI.bathrooms = Convert.ToInt32(reader["bathrooms"]);
    objI.garage = Convert.ToInt32(reader["garage"]);
    objI.tipo = new TipoInmueble() { id = reader["idTipoInmueble"], descripcion = reader["descripcionTipoInmueble"] };
    var subTipoInmueble = new subTipoInmuebleMapper().obtenerPorId(objSubTipo.id);            
    objI.ciudad = Convert.ToString(reader["ciudad"]);
    objI.barrio = Convert.ToString(reader["barrio"]);
    return objI;
}
```

Espero entiendas la idea

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, sabía que tenía un ejemplo así por algún lado pero no podía encontrarlo y no recordaba bien como era, ya quedó funcionando, saludos y de nuevo, gracias! Por cierto, lo único que faltó fue la conversión en el tipo.